# Window management in Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't work anymore

Tags: window

I need some help about the window management in Ubuntu 12.04.

When I drag a window to a side of my screen, the window doesn't fit to the half screen, like it was before.

Does anyone have this problem ?
Thanks !